# AWS calculator, data processed by ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

Can somebody explain what is a "Total Data Processed by all ELBs" in AWS calculator(http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html).

- What exactly "data processed" means ?
- What is counted ? Headers ? Body ?
- What about HTTP POST file uploads ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The charge is for...

> the data transferred through the Elastic Load Balancer
>
> http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/pricing

That would be requests and responses, headers and bodies, uploads and downloads, and presumably the associated overhead of TCP.