# AWS ELB "data processing"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

In [all of ELB's official pricing literature](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/pricing/) the pricing model for ELB seems to be partially based on GB of "data processing." For instance, right from that page, the current price of an ELB instance is:

> $0.025 per Elastic Load Balancer-hour (or partial hour)...[and]...$0.008 per GB of data processed by an Elastic Load Balancer

However my *understanding* of ELB is that its a load balancer, so what kind of "data" could it possibly be "processing"? I would have imagined the pricing to be based on number of requests serviced over a given point in time.

Comment: All the data that ultimately reaches the EC2 instances (behind the ELB) or is sent out is "processed" by the load-balancer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AWS calculator, data processed by ELB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30100620/aws-calculator-data-processed-by-elb)